# Swift: How to dismiss SLCAlertView when user touches out of AlertView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `SLCAlertView` and want to dismiss Alert View when user touches out of alertview.
But if I display `SLCAlertView` `touchesBegan` method is not working and can't tap action when user touches screen.

And I found some answers on stackoverflow but it's not working also.
Here's what I've tried.

```
let transparencyButton = UIButton(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
transparencyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.view.insertSubView(transparencyButton, belowSubView: alert.view)
self.transparencyButton.addTarge(self, action: #selector(ChartViewController.closePopupBtnTapped), forControlEvents:. TouchUpInside)
```

And Here's `closePopupBtnTapped` function.

```
func closePopupBtnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    printf("close")
    self.alert.hideView()
}
```

It even can't print "close".
Is there anybody who knows solution?